# how to pass value from javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass value to html id attribute.
So, I am getting value from laravel php controller

**Javascript**

```
        $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
        // alert($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""))
        var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
        console.log(id);

        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data:{'id':id},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
          }
       });
```

**html Blade**

```
                     <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs_content">
                            @foreach ($routes as $route)
                                <li >
                                    <a href="#{{ $route->id }}" id="ad" data-toggle="tab">
                                        {!! $route->name !!}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content blog_tabs">
                            <div class="tab-pane" name="schedule" id="tab-{{ $route->id}}" >

                                @foreach ($tabSchedule as $schedule)
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $schedule->schedule_number}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endforeach    
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

so here is picture of what i want to pass:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Query the element and set the id attribute:

```
success: function(data){
     $('.tab-content .tab-pane').attr('id', data.id)
}
```

But I don't get it. Why are you dynamically setting an id when you can do it in something a bit more acceptable like in a class, or a custom attribute eg `data-id`. And then just access the element through the class or attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could give your hidden field a unique id for example:

`<input type="hidden" name="smname" id="smname" />`
and then in javascript:

`document.getElementById('smname').value = data();` 
I hope I have helped you